# How to change default browser in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

It's default Internet Explorer old version so it won't work with youtube correctly, I tried searching for that option to change browser in Visual Studio but I found it as blocked, neither blocked or not changable. Like if I add "Web Browser" element.

Answer (score 0):

C#:

```
        var AppName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
        using (var Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true))
            Key.SetValue(AppName, 99999, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
```

and now insert Webbrowser element.

Comment: umm it will only change the url but internet explorer will still remain

Comment: yea but it will be upgraded it emulates a better browser (only works on windows 10 I think)